# ACE Editor Custom Highlighting Rule

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I can't seem to find how to create a custom syntax highlighting rule for the ACE code editor.

My editor is configured for PHP mode as follows (and is working perfectly);

```
    var phpeditor = ace.edit("php_inc");
    phpeditor.setTheme("ace/theme/dreamweaver");
    phpeditor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/php");
    phpeditor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
    });
```

What I would like the editor to do is to treat all instances of %%variable%% (with any text between the percent signs) to be highlighted with a custom rule and treated as a variable.

For example;

```
<?php echo %%my_variable_name%%; ?>
```

Is there a way of extending the editor to allow this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to modify php_highlight_rules file and add https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/php_highlight_rules.js#L900
a rule

```
{
    token: "variable",
    regex: "%%\\w+%%"
}
```

doing this dynamically instead, is a bit harder as ace doesn't provide convenient way to hook into mode creation, if you need to do that, perhaps you should open an issue on ace site on github.

Comment: Thanks for this - the highlighter is now recognizing them, but I still get a warning about there being a syntax error. Do you know where else I need to add code to get ACE to see these as valid PHP?

Comment: Yo can add `value = value.replace(/%%(\w+)%%/g, "$$$1")` in php worker https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.3/lib/ace/mode/php_worker.js#L58

Comment: I am now trying to extend this functionality to Javascript and CSS edit modes as well. I am successfully able to update their highlight_rules files, but can't seem to figure out how to edit their worker files so that the percent symbols are accepted as valid syntax - do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What did you try? it can be achived same way as for php you just need to pick a valid variable name https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.3/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js#L118

Comment: I attempted to use the same form of the code you gave me previously, but the worker files for JS and CSS appear to be of a different structure - what (and where) do in need to include? (Sorry if this is a bit of a beginner question ;) )

Comment: I already showed you a line where: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.3/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js#L118, as for what: the line you included for php should work for js too.

Comment: Thank you! You are awesome! I had been making a mistake in editing the $$$1 part - all is working great now.